# optimizar mapeo de entidades con JPA

Tags: java, jpa, optimización

soy algo nuevo en jpa , lo que estado intentando es mapear una tabla de mi BD  de la tabla Usuario la cual se divide en 2 tipos ,que son Usuarios Naturales y jurídicas pero las personas jurídicas  tiene datos de ruc y organización al que pertenece

```
public class Usuario implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_usuario")
    private int id_usuario;

    private String nombre;

    private String apellido;

    @Column(name = "dni", length = 8)
    private int dni;

    @Column(name = "user_name")
    private String user_name;

    @Column(name = "Clave")
    private String Clave;

    @Column(name = "Correo_Electronico", insertable = false)
    private String Correo_Electronico;

    @Column(name = "telefono", insertable = false)
    private String Telefono;

    @Column(name = "ruc", insertable = false, length = 11)
    private int ruc;

    @Column(name = "organizacion", insertable = false)
    private String Organizacion;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.DETACH })
    @JoinColumn(name = "persona_id_tipo_persona")
    private Tipo_Persona tipoPersona;
.
.
.
}
```

quisiera saber si se podria hacer de otra forma ,por que lo veo que no esta optimizado ya que al ingresar los usuarios tendre que ver el tema del ruc y crear un objeto con ese atributo. de antemano gracias

Comment: Tal vez te serviria que la entidad personas juridicas extienda a usuarios naturales

Answer (score 2):

Deberias realizar una herencia simple. Contarias con 3 clases:

- `TipoPersona`: Contendra todos los datos compartidos entre usuarios.
- `UsuariosNaturales`: No tendra atributos extras ya que los heredara
- `UsuariosJuridicos`: Tiene los atributos extras correspondientes

Ambos Usuarios heredarian de `TipoPersona` de la siguiente manera:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
 public class TipoPersona implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_usuario")
    private int id_usuario;

    private String nombre;

    private String apellido;

    @Column(name = "dni", length = 8)
    private int dni;

    @Column(name = "user_name")
    private String user_name;

    @Column(name = "Clave")
    private String Clave;

    @Column(name = "Correo_Electronico", insertable = false)
    private String Correo_Electronico;

    @Column(name = "telefono", insertable = false)
    private String Telefono;
 }


@Entity
@Table(name="Usuarios_Naturales")
public class UsuariosNaturales extends TipoPersona {

}

@Entity
@Table(name="Usuarios_Juridicos")
public class UsuariosJuridicos extends TipoPersona {
    @Column(name = "ruc", insertable = false, length = 11)
    private int ruc;

    @Column(name = "organizacion", insertable = false)
    private String Organizacion;
}
```

El resultado son 2 tablas: `Usuarios_Naturales` y `Usuarios_Juridicos` con Id unico compartiendo los atributos necesarios.

Espero que te sea util!

Comment: gracia me sirvió .